# Creating an embedded document by getting data from another sub document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a document which looks like,

```
org: {
        "name": "tera",
        "orgLocation": {
            "street":"xyz",
            "postal Code": "45893",
            "latitude": "64.23456",
            "longitude": "62.75469"
         }
     }
```

now I want to make latitude and longitude as a separate sub document keeping the  so that the document looks like:

```
 org: {
     "name":"tera",
     "orgLocation": {
         "street":"xyz",
         "postal Code":"45893",
         "latitude":"64.23456",
         "longitude":"62.75469" 
       },
     orgGeo: {
         "latitude":"64.23456",
         "longitude":"62.75469" 
     }
  }
```

As am new to mongoDB am unable to figure out how to?

Can any one help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update your document using values of existing fields in the same document you need to loop over each document using the [**`.forEach`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method and update each document with ["Bulk"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) operations for maximum efficiency.

```js
var bulk =  bulk = db.test.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),
    count = 0;

db.test.find({ "org": { "$exists": true } }).forEach(function(doc) {
    var latitude = doc["org"]["orgLocation"]["latitude"],     
        longitude = doc["org"]["orgLocation"]["longitude"]; 
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).update({    
        "$set": { 
            "org.orgGeo.latitude": latitude,
            "org.orgGeo.longitude": longitude 
        } 
    }); 
    count++; 
    if (count % 100 == 0) { 
        // Execute per 100 operations and re-init.    
        bulk.execute();     
        bulk = db.test.initializeOrderedBulkOp(); 
    } 
})

// Clean up queues
if (count % 100 != 0)
    bulk.execute();
```

---

After running this query your documents will look like this:

```js
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("55fd008f6606c68eb1d64934"),
        "org" : {
                "name" : "tera",
                "orgLocation" : {
                        "street" : "xyz",
                        "postal Code" : "45893",
                        "latitude" : "64.23456",
                        "longitude" : "62.75469"
                },
                "orgGeo" : {
                        "latitude" : "64.23456",
                        "longitude" : "62.75469"
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to replicate the same but its throwing:                             TypeError: Cannot read property 'orgLocation' of undefined
    at (shell):2:40
    at DBQuery.forEach (src/mongo/shell/query.js:414:9)
    at (shell):1:25

Comment: It says it cannot read property 'orgLocation' of undefined at shell

Comment: Am unable to join the room as i don't have 20 credits

Comment: Are you using the right collection? because this means that either you are not using the right collection or some of your documents don't have the `org` field? What is the output of `your_collection_name.find({org: {$exists: false}})`?

Comment: am using the correct collection, and am getting data for the above query.For some of the documents i don't have orgLocation

Comment: In this case you can only update documents with `org` field. Edited my answer.

Comment: when am trying to use the same code of yours it saying: syntax error unexpected end of input

Comment: @ram put the last `bulk.execute()` call inside a block `if (count % 100 != 0) {
    bulk.execute(); }` also you may need to remove the comments. line start with `//`